# The form for flagging an answer obscures the answer being flagged

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I've been noticing something about flagging answers that I forgot to put into a question until today ... when you flag an answer, the modal form that appears is covering the answer that was flagged.

[image: I did not flag this answer for reals!]

Sometimes the answer is so clearly in a certain category that it's enough to click a single radio button and move on, but based partly on [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/how-do-we-address-a-posted-question-answer-pair-that-contains-multiple-moderati/2283#2283), I usually explain why I'm flagging an answer or a question.

I almost always want to make sure that I'm getting the details right, though, so I like to go back to the answer and check it before I finish. Because of the location of the flagging form, I have to copy any text I've already entered, close the form, read the answer again, flag it "again", and re-enter that text. (Or enter my comments in another app, flag the answer, and paste them in, hoping that I've not copied any unwanted characters in the process.)

It seems to me that it would be easier to manage this if one of two things could happen:

1. Allow us to move the form so that we can see the answer we're flagging, or
2. Pop up the form in a location (above the answer?) that doesn't obscure the answer.

Other solutions would be fine as well; as a web developer myself, I'm sensitive to layout issues, and there is a workaround for this in place. I just think it would be nice not to have to hop back and forth to explain exactly why I'm flagging an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The flag modal can now be moved by clicking around the header section and dragging it out of the way. You'll know your mouse is in the right place when you see the 4-direction 'move' cursor appear:

[image: Flag modal being moved]